# Numbers manager JAVA UML

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I have to do a UML which manages all types of numbers (complex, real, rational, integer, natural).
Program should be capable of add, substract, multiplicate and divide also different types of number.

This is my idea:

[image]

Should i implement methods in interface "matematica"?
How can i manage for example sum beetween two different types of numbers?
Should i improve the uml?

Comment: Extends is wrong for a Generalization. And your order of generalization is wrong too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to model your program:

[image]

You build a single interface with all the required methods and make the different classes implement it. Note the parameters and return values are all of the interface's type, so all classes may be handled as long as they implement `INumber`.

In case you need to use inheritance, make an abstract class and then make each class inherit from it, not the way your image shows (*chain* inheritance not possible because the numbers are not related to each other like that in maths).